AWS Beanstalk "Try add execute permission"
We have a java application running on a AWS Beanstalk Tomcat managed platform. We use circleCI with Maven to deploy the application which has some platform hook scripts that need to run. When deploying the environment and application, the eb-engine logs show "Try add execution permission" when attempting to run the hook scripts.
In the circleCI deployment script, we specifically chmod +x all of the .sh files in the hook directories (prebuild, predeploy, and postdeploy). We checked the git file permissions with git ls-files -s and got 755 for all of them and running git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh doesn't result in any changes. We also unzipped the resulting WAR file and checked the permissions with ls -l and got the expected -rwxr-xr-x for all of the scripts.
Any ideas as to why Beanstalk can't execute those hook scripts?
